# How to delete duplicates, save latest entry and copy data to remaining one?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

My goal is to remove duplicates, save the latest entry and copy specific column data to remaining row. So I have columns from A to E. If columns from A to C are duplicate, older row will be deleted and column E information will be copied to remaining row.

Here is an example:

```
cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5
 1     2     2     4     tax
 1     3     3     1     extra
 1     2     2     5     
 1     2     3     1     tax
```

**After macro**

```
cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5
 1     3     3     1     extra
 1     2     2     5     tax
 1     2     3     1     tax
```

So now, row 1 has been deleted and its 'cell5' information has been copied to row 3.

Here is the code (Deleting duplicates and saving the latest entry works, I just don't know how to save cell5 information and paste it to remaining row). !!EDITED!! (Code changed according to this post's answer by @RonRosenfeld)

```
Option Explicit

Sub remDup()
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, vRow As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, v As Variant

'Also changed here rgTable into rRes
Set rRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

vSrc = rRes
ReDim vRow(1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

Set dict = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    sKey = vSrc(I, 1) & "|" & vSrc(I, 2) & "|" & vSrc(I, 3)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        vRow(J) = vSrc(I, J)
    Next J

    If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
    dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=vRow
    Else 

        vRow(UBound(vRow)) = dict(sKey)(UBound(dict(sKey)))
        dict.Remove (sKey)
        dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=vRow
    End If
Next I

ReDim vRes(0 To dict.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
Next J

I = 0
For Each v In dict.Keys
    I = I + 1
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        vRes(I, J) = dict(v)(J)
    Next J
Next v

'here I try to get the new table into sheet2
Dim rRes As Range
Set rRes = rRes.Worksheet("Sheet2").Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the duplicate row that you keep always blank in column E?

Comment: What if the row being retained already has an entry in column 5?

Comment: @SJR not always, but the first row will overwrite to remaining row if its not blank in the new row. Sorry didn't clarify it earlier :)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Then it will just overwrite it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- suggest using a dictionary object, and storing the row contents as an array.
- then you can

  - write preceding duplicates cell5 content into that array
  - delete the previous key and add it back to re-order it
- The algorithm assumes that the last column in the duplicates will be blank, or should always be overwritten by the first of the duplicates. If that is not the case, you will need to specify how that should be handled.

Also, I used a different way of defining `rgTable` and also worked in VBA arrays as it is much faster than read/write from the worksheet.

Finally, I set the results range to be an offset of rgTable, but if you have this working, and prefer, you can overwrite the original, or put it on a different worksheet.

But this should get you started.

```
'Set reference to microsoft scripting runtime
'   or use late binding
Option Explicit

Sub remDup()
    Dim rgTable As Range, rw As Range
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, vRow As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, v As Variant

'should use fully qualified references to avoid confusion
'For example:
Set rgTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

'in VBA, much faster to work with arrays
vSrc = rgTable
ReDim vRow(1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

Set dict = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc) 'skip header row
    sKey = vSrc(I, 1) & "|" & vSrc(I, 2) & "|" & vSrc(I, 3)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        vRow(J) = vSrc(I, J)
    Next J

    If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=vRow
    Else 'add previous col5 to vrow
         'remove old key and re-enter to re-order

         'To overwrite a different column instead of the last column, replace
         '(in the line below) Ubound(vRwo)  and  Ubound(dict(sKey)) with the 
         'column number
        vRow(UBound(vRow)) = dict(sKey)(UBound(dict(sKey)))
        dict.Remove (sKey)
        dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=vRow
    End If
Next I

'create results array
ReDim vRes(0 To dict.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

'headers
For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
Next J

'Data
I = 0
For Each v In dict.Keys
    I = I + 1
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        vRes(I, J) = dict(v)(J)
    Next J
Next v

'write the results
'once it works ok, can overwrite original

Dim rRes As Range
Set rRes = rgTable.Offset(columnoffset:=2 + rgTable.Columns.Count).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

#### Source Data

[image]

#### Results

[image]

Comment: Wow @RonRosenfeld ! It works so well and so fast. I still have couple of questions (Im VERY new to VBA, so dont mind my questions..) If the cell5 (column that I want to copy to remaining row) isn't last column on the table, how can I change the location for it in the code? Next question: If I want to overwrite original table and not to do a new table, how can I do that? Your code is so nicely done and its so advanced, so I have little bit struggle to read it, Im sorry :)

Comment: @Aku See my edit in the code above for what you need to do to refer to some column other than the last column (as written, it refers to the last column).

Comment: @Aku  `rRes` is the range to which the results are written. You can set it to some other range than the offset from `rgTable` that I used. It needs to be the same size as `vRes` (the results array).  I would suggest, for audit purposes, not overwriting your original data, but you certainly can. Something like `Set rRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(1,1).Resize(Ubound(vRes,1)+1,Ubound(vRes,2))`. Suggest also you read the late Chip Pearsons article on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld and thanks again for your help. You are right about the audit purposes, and Im trying to move updated data into another sheet so the original one can be saved also, but Im having some troubles with the code. I have tried to change the code with your assistant and with the article and changed this: Dim rRes As Range
Set rRes = rRes.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2)) Also I changed from the beggining this: Dim rRes As Range but I still doestn work and gives me an error code. Is this right way to do it?

Comment: Im having hard time perceiving the arrays and ranges, thats why Im confused

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld :) I edited my post so it is easier to show what I have changed. Hope this is ok. Error code is 'Duplicate declaration in current scope'

Comment: @Aku Delete one of your `Dim rRes` lines

Comment: Now it gives error code 'supscript out of range' should I have Set rRes = rRes.Worksheet("Sheet2").Resize(UBound(vRes(J, 1)) + 1, UBound(vRes(J, 2))) this like this?

Comment: @Aku No.  Do it as I showed you in my comment above, and make sure you have worksheet named `Sheet2`.